# Pie-chart (or alternative) representation with negative values/liabilities

Tags: visualization, graphs

I'd like to represent graphically/visually a fund/portfolio by something that resembles a pie chart. But... the fund/portfolio contains things that have negative value (think of liabilities such as: accrued fees, FX hedging marks etc.) These are relatively quite small (e.g., less than 10%).

How do I graphically present such a portfolio? I like the pie chart, but other suggestions are welcome too. However, I'm not super enthusiastic about a single column bar chart. I'm hoping for some ingenious find.

Comment: I think I know what I'd like: a concentric pie chart where the inner pie contains the NAV and the leveraging bits, and the outer pie contains the constituents of the gross asset value. I've asked here http://superuser.com/q/920836/302527 how to make it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you have a look at the waterfall chart: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart

Comment: I think this is more suitable to represent different types/factors of gains/losses of which there may be, say 6, much less than the number of portfolio holdings, say 40. Still +1.